# Selecting a graphing library in Julia for speed and customizability

Tags: plot, julia

I found a vast number of libraries for plotting in Julia that includes the following:

`Winston`: 2D plotting for julia looks like it requires `Cairo` and `Color`. Examples look like it supports line plots, histograms, scatterplot, and regression.

`Gadfly`: Looks to support `Dataframes` and uses the `Color` library. Graphs has a fairly clean look to them. Supports boxplot, line plots, bar plots, histograms, scatter plots, regression, densities, and contours. Runs on vector graphics library `Compose.jl`

`Pyplot`: A wrapper for Matplotlib in python

`Gaston`: Basically a wrapper for GNUplot

Which graphing library is preferred for speed? Are one of the plots using a wrapper faster than the julia based ones?

I use `Matplotlib` so I am aware it is not the fastest, but has a lots of features. It seems like `Gadfly` would be the prefer julia based plotting library due to its ability to plot different graphs, is it customizable as `matplotlib` in terms of being able to control line thickness, point shapes, create dotted lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speed is a tough question to answer because it depends strongly on exactly what you are plotting, and what you are plotting to. There is not a fastest overall.

`Gadfly` has the best interface, I think, because it is in Julia and is written for Julia. `Compose` is also very powerful in its own right (see, e.g. [graph plotting](https://github.com/IainNZ/GraphLayout.jl)).

For publication-quality plots though, I feel you still need to use `PyPlot`/`matplotlib`. It has more control over how the plot appears - e.g. right now Gadfly doesn't support different dashed lines. I find myself using Gadfly where possible, and using PyPlot for more "final" graphics for black-and-white publication purposes.